# SQL Developer is changing my query's format

Tags: oracle, configuration, oracle-sqldeveloper, code-formatting

I just upgraded my OS to Windows 10, and Oracle SQL Developer has this strange behavior now. When I press the ENTER key, the query's format changes completely. For example, before:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
```

After:

```
Select * From Mytable
```

Does anyone knows how to fix this? Maybe some configuration that I had, has changed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SQL Developer menu, go to Tools->Preferences and then expand the 'Code Editor' section, and choose the 'Completion Insight' section. You will see something like this:

[image]

The behaviour you describe is because you have 'Change case as you type' ticked, and 'Initial Cap' selected. You can choose a different auto-format option from the drop down list; or untick the box to stop is modifying your code at all.

Comment: Cool, this helped me too! SQL Developer was annoying (it offers object names in all caps, for example) but I never bothered to read the documentation to figure out how to change that. This was perfect. Thanks!